# how to test if the wcf is really in streaming mode?

Tags: wcf, streaming

I have a operation contract that is like this:

```
public interface ISearch
{
    [OperationContract]
    System.IO.Stream DownloadFile(string file);

}
```

the binding is nettcpbinding, and when i set buffered and streamed transfer mode, the wcf seems both work.
so how can i test whether the wcf is working in streamed mode?

Answer (score 2):

Send back a file that is larger than your setting for `maxReceivedMessageSize` on your binding configuration (default is 64KB). If WCF is in `Buffered` mode, it should fail. If it's in `Streamed` or `StreamedResponse` mode, it should work.

Comment: I tested, it seems even in streamed mode, wcf fails because of the maxReceivedMessageSize is exceeded.

Comment: it could also fail because of a timeout - can you post your service code, and the service and client config, please?

Comment: the exception is not timeout exception. let me do more test. get back soon. i think the maxReceivedMessageSize always work either in buffered or streamed mode. see this post: http://haveyougotwoods.com/archive/0001/01/01/wcf-message-streaming.aspx its config always give a bigger value to maxReceivedMessagSize even in streamed mode

Comment: @marc_s, yeah. after test. it's pretty clear that maxReceivedMessageSize works either in buffered or streamed mode.

Comment: add some code here and further question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037521/why-i-can-use-bitmap-as-return-type-whehttp-stackoverflow-com-questions-1287815

Answer (score 0):

Probably a very crude method, but, you can use windows resource monitor to validate that wcf is actually streaming the file. Here I was streaming a large file from a service hosted in IIS. Read/s and Write/s clearly shows that the file is being read while streaming and is not buffered.

[image: Test if WCF is really streaming]